# Getting test eth

Tags: rinkeby

- I opened metamask
- Connected to Rinkeby test network
- Copied address
- Tweeted the address
- Copied link to tweet
- Posted the link to https://faucet.rinkeby.io/
- Requested ETH and my name appeared in the list

It's been 2 hours and my balance on my metamask connected to rinkeby is still 0

Am i doing something wrong? I have tried this multiple times with different post ids

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get some ETH for Ropsten Net (it's a test net just like rinkeby) here:
[https://faucet.dimensions.network/]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the account your are trying to send ether to is the correct one,  as well it could be that privacy mode is enabled in Metmask I had an issue with that